# Cookie not not getting set on browser

Tags: cookies, browser, setcookie

Cookie is not getting set on browser.
In response header my cookie looks like below

```
set-cookie: __Secure-tsid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJJZCI6ImFiYy54eXpAY2RmLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTYxODg2MDYwMSwianRpIjoiZmZzZGYiLCJpc3MiOiJ0cyBhdXRoIHNlcnZpY2UifQ.6VTchsmmVTn7vljiDHLv5UUhcrUsm8uYtbE0qFOquygnhoy9pCUpWOczvsKjb2J88Mw30eZqdTqTAyI07yDL1g; Path=/dashboard; Domain=example.com; Expires=Mon, 19 Apr 2021 19:30:01 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
```

I am not sure what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, No problem with set-cookie values (in my question above).
On chrome browser's dev tools cookies aren't shown until you visit the path for which cookie was set to.